# Почему нужно указывать объект в блоке synchronised?

Tags: java, многопоточность, объекты, synchronized

Почему нужно указывать объект? Ведь мы можем вообще не использовать этот объект в блоке.

Также чем отличается `synchronized(this)` от `synchronized(o)`(я знаю что значит `this`, чем отличаются блоки с разными объектами)?

И наконец, почему мы можем использовать операции `wait`, `notify` и т.п. с `Object o`, ведь он не поток?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ключевое слово `synchronized` является утверждением, которое в круглых скобках принимает выражение, возвращающее ссылку на объект. Поэтому его не нужно путать с методом, принимающим один параметр. И то, что используется в скобках - относится к самому утверждению, а не блоку кода, для которого это утверждение работает. Как и в любом другом блоке кода вы можете использовать ссылку на любой объект, если он доступен в области видимости, которая охватывает этот блок. Поэтому какую ссылку вы используете в утверждении `synchronized`, не имеет отношения к тому, будете ли вы ее использовать в блоке кода или нет.

Вот, что по этому сказано в [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.19):

> Утверждение `synchronized` получает блокировку взаимного исключения
>   (§17.1) от имени исполняющего потока, выполняет блок, а затем
>   освобождает блокировку. Пока исполняющий поток владеет блокировкой, ни
>   один другой поток не может получить блокировку.
>
> ```
> SynchronizedStatement:
>     synchronized ( Expression ) Block
> ```
>
> Тип выражения должен быть ссылочным типом, или возникает ошибка
>   времени компиляции.

---

И наконец, методы `wait()`, `notify()`, и `notifyAll()` принадлежат классу `Object`. Поэтому вы можете использовать их в любом классе, вы также можете использовать ссылку на объект, для вызовов этих методов из этого объекта, имеющего эту ссылку. Так как впрочем все унаследованные методы доступны в классе без использования ссылки. Ссылка `this` указывает на *этот* объект, поэтому ее указывать необязательно для вызовов наследуемых методов, в то время как для других объектов это необходимо. Поток тоже является объектом, потому, что  создается из класса `Thread`, поэтому если методы вызываются внутри класса, то принадлежат ему.

Comment: Т.е., если я напишу o.wait(), то поток остановится, пока я не нотифаю его?(o - экземпляр Object)

Comment: Ну да, так и есть.

Answer (score 1):

```
Также чем отличается synchronized(this) от synchronized(o)
```

ничем, все зависит от того что вы будете делать с объектом который по которому синхронизировались, возможно вы захотите передать его в метод или предоставить доступ к нему из вне.

```
И наконец, почему мы можем использовать операции wait, notify и т.п. с Object o, ведь он не поток?
```

Вот здесь у вас небольшой пробел в знаниях, вам необходимо почитать про понятие монитора. Вкратце у каждого объекта есть монитор, можете представлять его как флаг, когда вы пишете

```
synchronized(this) {...}
```

поток который заходит внуть этого блока захватывает монитор объекта this, таким образом другие потоки видят что монитор захвачен и не заходят внутрь.

Answer (score 0):

Если рассматривать оператор

```
synchronized (ссылка_ на_ объект) {
    // блок кода, который нужно синхронизировать
}
```

то здесь `ссылка_ на_ объект` обозначает ссылку на синхронизируемый объект.
Блок оператора `synchronized` гарантирует, что вызов метода, являющегося
членом того же класса, что и синхронизируемый объект, на который делается
`ссылка_ на_ объект`, произойдет только тогда, когда текущий поток исполнения
успешно войдет в монитор данного объекта.

В синхронизируемом блоке можно не объявлять оператор `synchronized` со ссылкой на объект тогда, когда вы точно используете метод, объявленный как `synchronized`. Если вы не имеете исходника, чтобы пере-объявить этот метод, то используете оператор `synchronized (ссылка_ на_ объект)`. Какой объект указывать - `this` или `o` - зависит от вашей программы. Если синхронизируется блок кода из текущего объекта, то он уже создан и ссылкой на него является `this`. Если этот метод в другом объекте, то его и указываете. Как-то так...