# Как решить проблему с synchronized методом в многопоточности Java?

Tags: java, многопоточность

Для достоверности буду оперировать цитатами из книги Брюса Эккеля - Философия Java (4-е издание).

**Логика нашей задачи будет простая:**
Имеется класс, в котором есть переменная `i`, которую будет увеличивать и метод, который, в свою очередь, и будет заниматься увеличением значения переменной `i`.

Создаем макет класса:

```java
public class AtomicityTest {
    private int i = 0;

    public int getValue() {
        return this.i;
    }

    public void evenIncrement() {
        i++;
        i++;
    }
}
```

У нас есть переменная `i`, к которой в дальнейшем будут обращаться несколько потоков. По этому поводу Брюс Эккель пишет:

> Если сразу несколько задач обращаются к полю, это поле следует объявить с ключевым словом volatile.

Хорошо, теперь поле нашего класса должно выглядеть следующим образом:

```java
private volatile int i = 0;
```

Но ниже он пишет:

> в виртуальной Java машине `инкремент` **не является атомарным**...

В примере в методе мы будем использовать `атомарную` операцию инкрементирования `++`. `Атомарная операция` - это:

> операция, которую не может прервать планировщик потоков — если она начинается, то продолжается до завершения, без возможности переключения контекста.

Что мы в итоге имеем? Получается, что операции `++` не является атомарной, следовательно, нету смысла объявлять её `volatile`, верно?

Читаем дальше

> Для управления доступом к совместному ресурсу вы для начала помещаете его внутрь объекта. После этого любой метод, получающий доступ к ресурсу, может быть объявлен как `synchronized`. Это означает, что если задача выполняется внутри одного из объявленных как synchronized методов, все остальные задачи не сумеют зайти в свои `synchronized`-методы до тех пор, пока первая задача не вернет управление из своего вызова.

На выходе имеем готовый класс:

```java
public class AtomicityTest implements Runnable {
    private int i = 0;

    public int getValue() {
        return this.i;
    }

    public synchronized void evenIncrement() {
        i++;
        i++;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            evenIncrement();
        }
    }
}
```

Так как первоначальное значение переменной `i` равняется `0`, а метод `evenIncrement()` прибавляет по `единице` к переменной, в итоге получаем только четные числа. Так как метод синхронизированный, то:

- поток № 1 зайдет в метод;
- заблокирует доступ в метод для других потоков;
- сделает так, чтобы переменная увеличилась на `2` (0, 2, 4, 6, 8 и т.д.)
- поток № 1 выйдет и разблокирует доступ к методу для других потоков.

Хорошо, теперь приступаем к тестированию:

```java
AtomicityTest at = new AtomicityTest();

        ExecutorService exec = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
        exec.execute(at);

        while (true) {
            int value = at.getValue();

            if(value % 2 != 0) {
                System.out.println("value: " + value);
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }
```

И тут чудеса. Получается так, что при тестировании мы на выходе получаем **нечетные** числа. Как такое возможно? Решение проблемы кроется в том, что метод, возвращающий значение `i` с именем `getValue()` должен быть объявлен таким образом:

```java
public synchronized int getValue() {
    ...
}
```

Но почему только так? Всё ведь подтверждено цитатами выше и должно работать, по логике, без синхронизированного метода `getValue()`.

Comment: `Но почему только так? Всё ведь подтверждено цитатами выше и должно работать, по логике, без синхронизированного метода getValue().` с чего бы это? Откуда такие выводы?

Comment: Про `volatile` [есть вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1271/183458), а насчет `synchronized getValue` - в цитате _"все остальные задачи не сумеют зайти в свои synchronized-методы до тех пор, пока первая задача не вернет управление из своего вызова"_ ведь не говорится, что "не сумеют зайти в любой метод" - не `synchronized` методы могут быть вызваны когда угодно

Comment: @Regent, точно. Как правильно теперь дать ответ на вопрос? Отвечайте, будем принимать...

Comment: Попробую растянуть комментарий на ответ

Comment: Синхронизованные методы очень похожи на синхронизованные блоки, если используется `synchronized(this)` в теле метода. См. [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/868528/204920) как надо использовать ключевое слово `synchronized`.

Comment: чтобы получать только четные числа нужно чтобы и метод getValue() был synchronized, так работает механизм, а то можно получить значение поля между двумя инкрементами. А так чтение поля тоже будет ждать своей очереди.

Comment: @Ansar Если сделать "чтобы и метод getValue() был synchronized", то это ударит по производительности, а также может привести к дедлокам.

Comment: Ну тогда внутри evenIncrement() должна быть только одна модификация счётчика, например добавлять сразу 2. А лучше использовать атомик классы, у них, говорят, оптимизация низкоуровневая.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Про `volatile` подробнее расписано, например, [в этом вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1271/183458). Если вкратце, то `volatile` это в первую очередь про видимость значения между потоками, а не про атомарность

В цитате

> все остальные задачи не сумеют зайти в свои synchronized-методы до тех пор, пока первая задача не вернет управление из своего вызова

говорится о том, что если вызван `synchronized` метод, то нельзя вызвать из другого потока другой `synchronized` метод

В [документации](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html) формулировка аналогичная:

> When one thread is executing a synchronized method for an object, all other threads that invoke synchronized methods for the same object block (suspend execution)

Всё это никак не противоречит тому, что можно параллельно вызвать не-`synchronized` метод, что и происходит на практике

Comment: В документации написано верно, но не следует цитировать английский текст.

Comment: @RomanC, а я, наоборот, приветствую первоисточник. Каждый сам для себя переведен.